# Encrypt and decrypt algorithm for image in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any algorithm to encrypt/decrypt the image in iPhone with password protection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of algorithms available through OpenSSL, like AES and 3DES. OpenSSL isn't easy to use but it's mighty. Also, there are a lot of tutorials out there. For example, [here's a sample on how to en/decrypt with AES](http://saju.net.in/code/misc/openssl_aes.c.txt) in plain C.

And then there's the CommonCrypto library. See the question *[AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)*, the part you're likely most interested in are [methods that extend NSData for encryption and decryption with AES](http://pastie.org/426530).

Comment: This algorithm used for encrypt and decrypt text format.How to achieve this for UIImage?

Comment: @Sezhian: [Convert the UIImage to NSData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240765/nsdata-to-uiimage) and then [use the NSData category I've linked to encrypt with AES](http://pastie.org/426530). The other way round is easier: decrypt with the NSData category and then use [UIImage imageWithData:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithData:).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CommonCrypto library that's available in the iOS SDK.