# Iphone Encryption on UIImage - kCCBufferTooSmall error on AES 256 encryption

Tags: iphone, encryption, uiimage, aes, nsdata

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016318/encrypt-and-decrypt-algorithm-for-image-in-iphone) thread, and the encryption techniques mentioned there is working well. But not in all cases.

**Requirement:**

Simple, take one image, encrypt it, and store the encrypted data. Later, get the encrypted data, decrypt it, recreate the original image and show.

**What I have done**

From the above mentioned thread, I found [NSData additions for AES 256 encryption](http://pastie.org/426530). I tried to use it but with partial success. This is the code

```
//encryption
NSData *srcData       =   UIImageJPEGRepresentation(srcImage, 1.0);
NSLog(@"srcData length : %d",[srcData length]);
NSData *encryptedData =   [srcData AES256EncryptWithKey:KEY];
NSLog(@"encrypted data length : %d",[encryptedData length]);

........

//later..
//decryption
decryptedImage  =   [UIImage imageWithData:[encryptedData AES256DecryptWithKey:KEY]];
imageView.image =   decryptedImage;
```

**What is happening**

For a small image, say image with resolution 48*48, this code is working successfully. But when I run  the code in an image with higher resolutions, say 256 * 256, the method `AES256EncryptWithKey` failing with error `kCCBufferTooSmall` (-4301).

**Questions**

1. Does AES 256 impose any limit on the size (in bytes) of the payload
   to be encrypted?
2. If the answer to first question is **YES**, then what kind of
   encryption algorithm to use in iphone, to encrypt image (probably
   big ones)?
3. If the answer to the first question is **NO**, then why this error?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, not really. Some hash functions do have a maximum, but that's more in the order of 2^64, so generally you don't have to worry.
2. N/A
3. It has probably something to do with the `dataWithBytesNoCopy` in combination with the `malloc` call, but it is hard to find out without actually running the code.

Note that that wrapper is pretty braindead, as it does require encrypting all at once, without using `CCCryptorUpdate`. It does not use an IV which jeopardizes security. It handles the keys as strings. Finally, it creates too big a buffer size for decryption. You are better off creating your own using a more reliable source.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I don't have any iOS devices to test this on.