# how to upload a picture in iphoto to a webserver?

Tags: iphone, file-upload, uiimagepickercontroller, filepath, iphoto

I want to take a photo or pick a picture from iphoto library and then upload it to webserver.
Use  imagePickerController I can only get a UIImage Object,I can't know it's file path or file type(png,jpg,etc.). I have google for a long time but still can't find a solution. Any one can help me? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the raw data from the image.  Take a look at questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240765/nsdata-to-uiimage).

Then, just set the appropriate MIME type on your http request and shoot the data up to the server.

Comment: I have tried that way and  upload image to server successfully.But first I need to know the file type  before use UIImageJPEGRepresentation or UIImagePNGRepresentation. Cause in photo library there are png image and jpg image.

Comment: I have found the way to get the file extension,in function,imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:,we can use [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL],it like assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000002&ext=JPG". so that is a JPG file. Thank You!