# How to convert NSData value to UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSData to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240765/nsdata-to-uiimage)

How do I convert a NSData value to UIImage?

Comment: You have the solution here:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240765/nsdata-to-uiimage

Comment: -1 The first result of searching for [ios] nsdata to uiimage has the answer you want.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can get [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from [NSData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as follows:

```
NSData *data = yourData;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

or

```
NSData *data = yourData;

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
....
[image release];
```