# convert UIImage to NSData and back to UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

I have to populate table cell from database and images are on device.
I've to store that image in `imageDataObject`, how to convert that `UIImage` to `NSData`.
Please suggest, I tried many solution but it's not converting back that `NSData` to `UIImage`.

```
    cell.textLabel.text = [[offlineImageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageName];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [self retrieveImageFromDevice:[[offlineImageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageName]];
    NSData* data = ??????????;
    ImageData *imageDataObject = [[ImageData alloc] initWithImageId:[[offlineImageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]imageId] 
    imageName:[[offlineImageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageName] imageData:data];
    [imagesArray addObject:imageDataObject];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert UIImage to NSData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476929/convert-uiimage-to-nsdata)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert NSData value to UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101526/how-to-convert-nsdata-value-to-uiimage)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSData to UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240765/nsdata-to-uiimage)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To convert `UIImage` to `NSData`, use either `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality)` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage *image)`

To convert `NSData` to `UIImage`, use `[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]`

So your example could look like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[offlineImageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageName];
UIImage *thumbnail = [self retrieveImageFromDevice:[[offlineImageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageName]];
NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail);
ImageData *imageDataObject = [[ImageData alloc] initWithImageId:[[offlineImageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]imageId] imageName:[[offlineImageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageName] imageData:data];
[imagesArray addObject:imageDataObject];
```

References: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html
https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: What if I do not know the image representation wether png or jpg? Is it a problem if I use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` for jpg too?

Comment: @János - This will not cause a problem.

Answer (score 9):

Try With this:

Use this for convert `UIImage` to `NSData`.

```
  NSData *imagedata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnail);
```

Try this for image data convert back to `UIImage`

```
  UIImage *image= [UIImage imageWithData:imagedata];
```

Comment: How the hell do i know the UIImage is PNG? What if it's JPEG?

Comment: A UIImage is neither jpg or png. it's a raw bitmap. PNG and JPG are a format to transport an image in a smaller format

Answer (score 4):

in Swift version:

```
    let imageData = image!.pngData()
    let imageFromData = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624096-pngdata

Comment: Simple, effective! Thanks!

Comment: Simple doc update, as now 'UIImagePNGRepresentation' has been replaced by instance method 'UIImage.pngData()'

Answer (score 0):

Use if-let block with Data to prevent app crash & safe execution of code, as function UIImagePNGRepresentation returns an optional value.

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "TestImage.png") {
    if let data:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
       // Handle operations with data here...         
    }
}
```

> Note: **Data** is Swift 3 class. Use Data instead of NSData with
>   Swift 3

Generic image operations (like png & jpg both):

```
if let img = UIImage(named: "TestImage.png") {  //UIImage(named: "TestImage.jpg")
        if let data:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) {
               handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
        } else if let data:Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0) {
               handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
        }
}

*******
func handleOperationWithData(data: Data) {
     // Handle operations with data here...
     if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        // Use image...
     }
}
```

By using extension:

```
extension UIImage {

    var pngRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
    }

    var jpegRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)
    }
}

*******
if let img = UIImage(named: "TestImage.png") {  //UIImage(named: "TestImage.jpg")
      if let data = img.pngRepresentationData {
              handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
      } else if let data = img.jpegRepresentationData {
              handleOperationWithData(data: data)     
     }
}

*******
func handleOperationWithData(data: Data) {
     // Handle operations with data here...
     if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        // Use image...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Data from Image:**

Try JPEG or PNG representation depending on your image format:

> UIImageJPEGRepresentation
>
> Returns the data for the specified image in JPEG format.

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

> UIImagePNGRepresentation
>
> Returns the data for the specified image in PNG format

```
NSData * UIImagePNGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image
);
```

**Example:**

```
extension UIImage {

    var pngRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)
    }

    var jpegRepresentationData: Data? {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1.0)
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
let data = myImage.jpegRepresentationData
let data1 = myImage.pngRepresentationData
```

**Convert Image from Data:**

```
let image = UIImage(data: data)
```