# Image is in NSData format I want to convert into image files

Tags: ios, image, nsdata

Image is in `NSData` format I want to convert into image files plz can any one help me Thanks in Advance.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] imagesAssetArray]count]; i++) {

        NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] imagesAssetArray]count]];

        NSLog(@"Imges:%@", [[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] imagesAssetArray] objectAtIndex:i]);


        for (NSDictionary *dict in [[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] imagesAssetArray]) {

            if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypePhoto){

                if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]){
                    UIImage* image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
                    [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate load_uploadingImage:[image fixOrientation]];
                    NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate get_upload_image], 1.0f);
                    [Base64 initialize];
                    NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
                    strEncoded = [strEncoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];

                    NSMutableDictionary *param = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    [param setObject:strEncoded forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d",i]];
                    [temP addObject:param];

                } else {
                    NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = %@", dict);
                }
            }
        }
    }



    [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate startIndicator];

    NSMutableArray *totalrequest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [totalrequest addObject:param];

    [RequestAndResponseHandlers helparucommonRequestAndResponseHandlerWithParam:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:totalrequest,@"request",nil] methodName:methodName completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *response) {

        NSLog(@"Response :%@", response);

        if ([[response valueForKeyPath:@"response.httpCode"] integerValue]==200) {
          [[iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate appdelegate] navigateTo:[iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate publicView ]];
        }
        else {
            [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate alertWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Please try again!"];
        }

        [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate stopIndicator];

        [self.containerTbl reloadData];
    }];

}
```

output Image file is in nsdata

```
4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAAEcKADAAQAAAABAAAC9gAAAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs%2BEJ%2B/8AAEQgC9gRwAwERAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5%2Bv/EAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwABAgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5%2Bjp6vLz9PX29/j5%2Bv/bAEMAAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf/bAEMBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAf/dAAQAjv/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A/kj%2BM%2Bl3mkzfCj4jxwGGCDVNV8L3evJLDc2Opz6faxjTLy5ldpJrCPX9GEgLO11FZW6y3NqokiFm35vw5ChDC4uhQpOm7wdtdb6JR1TbjdPtZNO28f0riOrQhNThrFu1/L7lvp1Vt7K1ypovxEsvDFsNA8H6FB4ai8XC7OpfZprzU/DHiG20fXp7OPUtHkvbk2yXumx20aa1f2X2B7xYXeSC2jAmqs2ybF4mVKWJmp4ejC7VoxceaKveyVotpxV27K3dxJybMoYVqdJ3deynZt2UdtH69Hr1Ur%2B7658UfGXiHW/hHrmiW1voOt%2BJ9F8e6Z4l1rVLTTb27vnuLe0l068LyX13d3dxc273ui/ZL5YYbGPS0nitp7srIqfN5PhsNhMZXwtdyjhq6lytvlTfNdq%2Bt01ePK27ystNo/RZh7StRjiIvmsuZ9%2Blnr16628u0t74TfE6y%2BJHglI/iR5GteIvApXxWkjQaXM9z4JiI05/DM2mTT2o1of2pcx3E3mRyzQafaXVhqsKRy2F%2BvncS5RWy2vhcbld6acZYffVylUbTWj1svd5WrvVO8XA9HKM0lmlGUZtR5IuOv8AdVt1a700Xre97nQeN/2im0v9oCygt7e6k8Ja9pPhK/8AD2l%2BJWs9IsdC1KB0utbjj0TwjYyaVbQ6rdrJe6dZXLXEmk2l5FafZ2ubgBeelw3gMy4Vq4qVJ/X6M5e0kk06rXvW15U371%2BWzslroePLNZYbMnh5aqouWO1/u80mtXrra2p7R4c0u4a18YeN4rTRtW/4SufToPHPhrRb4sXBvLu9sfEMNlHYxXkmpvbh5NcQLYy6fdvHfW1xp2l5jf8APcXjaftcFhK2Dr0aeD5IwrVY2j7tnKKvzLljJN09bW3UnO0ejA4FwxGIxN177bl0dm9Nt3b0frZuXyYlzoFxL4qvvFGly6b4U8USaro3iDXf7JuLm8hd5lg04RQWa5hs9IM3kaj9kjQ3EG3U4Ip5YrW3X9Hw%2BIrVIYWnhmvrOGjQxFOLlC0oOEZqTlJr4koNRbsrtK3wx2xkqUqLeiaTT6ap2to3p0bVr9ddD1K6%2BE7/AA%2B%2BF95Gbi81m68HW2m65qNpBolv4n8NXmi%2BI0uoNV8Tz62H/tyHQdFhtNLkhgu9LMkd1qV5azanLptr56ckc1pZ5m87L2c5wWHgpqMKvtqbukrOMFKUrRcpSgrXaSk4xl52Hx%2BIoQVGrG9Cq/Zydr2Wurbu9nfRapatJnnHijxdoi%2BFvFPg7wDd6t4Q8QX%2Bn6frGuabaXn27SbHU9MvWl%2B0eBptPjt7vUtIu7CeM6WyNcSQaX53nz6oiw3NfUZbh8X7enPEKPscO5ckZtOc%2BXV%2B9H3Yyfm7vopL4ebM44em1QwGtSau7a%2B89rPRbXS0ld6NKx8j/GXwhYyX8niKyvbLTtVi/wCEbtLrT1urQLq13d6NazXniC2uIClsl3qeoObvUbS3RDZ6g1%2B0xXKCvvMrxMnTmsVG1Ozcd21DpfyUXa%2Bt1vay5vjMzw0XUh9Wb9vDljVvpeoviavdav0V%2B56t8HfHFhewSaP8UNdGhafP4dtfD8D6lok8P26ymuJoYba2vbOCWK805r17i5kupxA%2BlS2800c07XMyJ42c4GSpxxODvJQqyq2Tbiko6%2B7paXna7skrXSPXyvFVG3h6ukvZeS5tdEuv4vr35Y%2BQfGfTPH%2BleLbHQNTS0u4tAsNLufDF3oMa3j2vhzUxFb6DbNeW6CZYFMETW1tcjMd5MZIkEV4qP72WKi8HCvWb5q0UqkZO/vW95u6738%2Bl%2Bp4%2BZPEU8VyRje7fL0Wuit107Xa2va95ZGrarB8R7LxE%2BvaZqEfxA0TRYJmvtssqXFt4fk8m/SW1QJdWdwLFyt0snm28P2dZU%2By7pErWMIYOcFSadGpNuL31k011Wrv31ts1ZkOU8TTlGpFqVN21XbRvZef39LtRzPhp4s1rTb6x8PabrWsWB1jVPsE%2Bn6esc9jqkGpwLYXNpdwyPHMyTRE2nmxTs9vHIs0HlTQ4ZZlThWoTr4lrljBqLelrWaf8r0tund9ldS2wOJcL4amneW%2Bl1yeV2vTR37pfZ%2Bnrf4GfDeXwr4uX4k%2BKtF8Ea5o2uSaRpt/pNve6zLp2q2VzGs811oEf2TUdV8L6hBqq2mr6naW0t/pOpaJE8a3kUohuPBoZvj6eMpUcKpTwLpNTk9LX0sr32a6yd1ooppyPYeS4CUPbwajXerjzXu/nZdei3eqSty/Our6Xqng%2BCa00W50zUo/BPi86yPGuh3Mt3Zz3EgitNGXSdTs3jmit9Tax821ivrSwuIbyNoJ5EklaGvfpTjiKKlG6bj/K9U1fVbNq/e3qmeJUhXoYi2llLfpfuuuva1t9Za8uxq7%2BItA03w78S9MWz8zXtMkntr2ylU3%2BltBdzXF/dixDkwWcN6HtIruW2YJ5UscPkyRWstc0cNTqT%2Br1muXnTs1q2n7uq20d7a9u6j0YiviIU1Wpq8pJRdm769t303aslo07e94Zd6teX19f6hfObi71K5vL67d5Chkur2c3U8nRpHMskrybVxkNtGQM17Um4xhCi/dS5b/h1Vla1lrr2ukz52SU6vPWb5t2rXd%2Bq0atv0Vr6u97HXfDXxPpvg7xroHiTVtKsdZ0/S9ZtL%2BbR9Rs7fUtMvIoZR5kV/pt7BcR3sEkZmhWNghV2imtzHOEuIufMKFephJOlJe1acW1LZ219NLLVfej0MDXhTrx9orQT912VmtLdb77aab30sfZnib4o/C74wfGfQYINOTTPDmq%2BELzRL6W/kS1ij1278Ua7r%2BhajYBf7MfTp9FiudO0m1eUzSXlol9bswiuUVfmaGExtDATaj78cRCV0ov3dFyppuOtv71mk1y6qX0ccZhcTiY0Jy9z2U3e%2BnMk%2BXWye9l1fTrc%2BZ/FHgjxt8Lb%2BPxVa%2BVeaNrX9t21t4hsY0uNI1O3lv7vSrpJrCW2VYXn8qWK70i5Eg/eWSNtkaAL7%2BExdCpCFC69uo6xctF1evMr6LVrfV%2B6mz5zFYevCtUnFP2F9NPs63utO1tG9/taM8kvXgk2TRFkuZ/MW%2BSRnHmNvDB4pd7SEXCjMqsBsYMXaYncveoOnKUG7vR38mtuu1/L0d0zzJpSV47atdX1/w9fL5L7WT5e4zeUshhiUkNjb5Y6liB8gRWwMkjbwc8fNMpWkvJN799Oz/X5bhGLSfr91/m7/1otWX7S0WQ%2Ba9yFkWLcgl%2BZJCGVVQjBJyXHzMuFXc2DgCk5vp%2Bd393Ivz%2B8o9J%2BHSm8%2BIXgbT7TTI/FMQ8XaDaWfh3UbSW9t9SEl7aQS6RcWFoJp76xmd5rdbW0ikkvrYTlUMv7teTHXp0HUV1KUXK61a5b6u17bb3dnba/uehl0faVXGTSjdat2TXZbXd3trf8D0n46aRolv4v8byeHLVbex0DxprejoJ1nULYvdy27JCJFyHtZ4Vit/tCxzBN9u28%2Bai8%2BWO%2BHqcys5NNK69He36PTTcvMoxp1eSOq/m%2Bd2uu/yttvdnz3eRz3xkW/8A3WqQxtcRuGQCZJGEhgnEbGOOadzGbdhtTzMCQKhZ29Sm7RcdrvbT%2Bv16vqeTOLdtL2vp32/rb7jEWeRY/Jk8xJEDITjmM7jlW6mJchN0QAQ7eNuaUoXk2l21%2B6%2Bml9fPXysOCsrWS12X9fImkuJnRN8bYuYo5S2xdtyYmeMTAlQWbeCkqwssWRg/OFFXJNxtpf8AD80/x%2B8pq%2BhpX%2BhPDottqLCNJRH9okVXL77ad40tmfGFUq2Yud7jOHYbc1VOpra2j87%2Bn2Vv106brTlK1JJRltqvV7WfTtr0V%2Btkjlhg5LrgjHc9T9D1/D1yecV0GMlZ/Jfl8/z%2B%2BwMihs%2Bpyc%2Bo6D9fXp1/uUrq9uv9f1b5iTs0/P8Ar%2Bvl1LMcgbYCMAqUPOBgn9OwJwPwyRWU/ify/I1549/wJXbawZcqUYK45JO3ng9MHAzyM9cjAWlVim77O3a/ff3o/wBdre9V7mp/aKmKRnQEyNEZI8Fg6hMGQYGfNCFIuCciPgDhqxUJXXk11svuu/Xf7gbS/rt%2BYtvNeSRwssssgtAttbF3Di2gJl8qOMSGVTF%2B8fcWVlyvUEhqVR67bLyX/A1v3%2B69o6Qi373T%2Blrrp6W%2Be6OzgmGl20ULLJDMbVXu0mykkysqvCI1k3pJEIpE8wqYxjY8TFWyuSneSSX4/wD2qX5W63vY2c0oNPfpfy1S
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert NSData value to UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101526/how-to-convert-nsdata-value-to-uiimage)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSData to UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240765/nsdata-to-uiimage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get UIImage from NSData like this

```
NSData *data = yourData;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: i didt get you can u make a two line of code plz

Comment: Where you want to show your image just paste the above code with your data name.

Comment: NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] imagesAssetArray]count]];
        
        NSData *data = images;
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        
        NSLog(@"Imges:%@", [[[ListingStep2Model sharedInstance] imagesAssetArray] objectAtIndex:i]);

Comment: Tell me exactly where do you want to show the image?

Comment: UIImage* image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
                [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate load_uploadingImage:[image fixOrientation]];
                NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate get_upload_image], 1.0f);
                //[Base64 initialize];
                UIImage *convertedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
                NSString *strEncoded = [Base64 encode:data];
                strEncoded = [strEncoded stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
                [tempArray addObject:strEncoded];

Comment: hear to iam passing the image

Answer (score 0):

U need just one line for this:

```
UIImage *convertedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:yourImageData];
```

Comment: i didt get you can u make a two line of code plz @ayan khan

Comment: just pass your NSData to it ,you don't need any extra line.

Comment: if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == ALAssetTypePhoto){

            if ([dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]){

                UIImage* image = [dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

                [iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate load_uploadingImage:[image fixOrientation]];

                NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate get_upload_image], 1.0f);
                [Base64 initialize];
                UIImage *convertedImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

Comment: first tell me,what you want to do,coz here you are directly getting image

Comment: when i select an image  n posting to server then the output is in nsdata formate i want to chainge in images

Comment: you should post to server the base64 string....

Comment: ya i have done but not getting