# Error occur while put a image stored as NSdata into the pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, nsdata

I use core Data to store my image as `NSdata`, so the image will be stored from another `TableViewController`

Now, I would try to put a image stored as a `NSData` into the `pickerView`

```
var restaurants:Restaurant!
var imageArray = [NSData]()

var dataArray1 = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageArray = [restaurants.image!]

    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        dataArray1.append((Int)(arc4random() % 10))
    }

    resultLabel.text = ""

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
}

@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    pickerView.selectRow(Int(arc4random())%94 + 3, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let pickerImage = UIImageView()

    if component == 0 {
        _ = imageArray[(Int)(dataArray1[row])]
    }

    return pickerImage
}
```

it looks like the view below, but the image inside should be my `NSData` files 
http://www.appcoda.com.tw/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/emoji-slotmachine.gif

When I run it, it always shut down.
I think the problem is that Array doesn't get the value from the Core Data?
Really need help, please.

Comment: What do you mean shutdown? Do you get an error message? Have you traced the failure to a specific piece of code; you need to slow things down and find the exact point it fails.

Comment: Thanks for your remind!

I got a Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 at line
imageArray = [restaurant.image!]

the fact is that I really don't know what it means!

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly converting your `NSData` representing a `UIImage` back to a `UIImage`. Because of this, the cast that you are trying to do fails every time.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240765/nsdata-to-uiimage):

To summarize for you:
To get a `UIImage`, you need this line somewhere:

```
image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```